# xampp erorr url not found

Tags: xampp, http-status-code-404

I've been trying to open this project of mine, but when i do localhost/agroculture it says the requested url was not found. Can someone please help??[this is what the error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBJFe.png)

my port is 80,i even tried changing it to port 81, then i also did localhost:80/agroculture before that but nothing works.
also my sql port is 3307.so when i open phpmyadmin,it shows localhost/localhost:3307/phpmyadmin(dont know if this is relevant to the problem or not).